# Xinetd disable stderr redirection

Tags: linux, shell, networking, service, xinetd

I just setup xinetd for one of my binary to run as a service. However it appears to me that both stdout and stderr is redirected into the socket stream.

Is there anyway to disable the stderr ? I try in the server field of xinetd setting: `server = binary 2>/dev/null` but it doesn't work

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a work-around by putting it in a bash wrapper which redirect the stderr to null, then put the script in the xinetd configuration.